# Can I detect Facetime screen shots?

Tags: screen-capture, facetime

Can I somehow know if the other caller is taking a photo (screenshot) while we are on FaceTime? I need to know if they are secretly taking photos of me.

Comment: As far as i know, you will never be sure that someone isn't secretly taking photos of you!!!

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no way to tell...unless, of course, they have their volume cranked and you can hear the camera shutter sound.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you hold the volume down button and home button at same time and hold during FaceTime it will tell you if someone if taking a screenshot of you.

edit: sorry, this is wrong. -owlswipe

Comment: This is like, literally blatantly false. Huh?

Answer (score -3):

You can detect if somebody screenshots you during Facetime.

Comment: *How* can you?​

Comment: This is...literally the best answer I've ever seen.